# C++ thread error: no type named type

Tags: c++, multithreading, methods, pthreads

I'm trying to use threads for the first time on a method of my class.

This is a simplified version of my code that results in the same error.

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

class Foo{
public:
    std::vector<int> DoThing() {
        return {1};
    }

    std::vector<int> DoThingMultiThread(unsigned int threads) {
        std::vector<int> values;
        std::vector<std::thread> threadVec(threads);
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < threads; ++i)
        {
            threadVec.at(i) = std::thread(&Foo::DoPartialThing, this, i, i, std::ref(values));
        }
        return values;
    }
private:
    void DoPartialThing(unsigned int value, unsigned int position, std::vector<unsigned int> &container) {
        container.at(position) = value;
    }

};
```

In the actual code I want each thread to fill a bigger chunk of the vector.

I have this code in a Clion project with the CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(ThreadTest)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS -pthread)

set(CMAKE_THREAD_PREFER_PTHREAD TRUE)
set(THREADS_PREFER_PTHREAD_FLAG TRUE)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp foo.hpp foo.cpp)
add_executable(ThreadTest ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

Whether I include the flag -pthread is irrelevant for the compilation, it always gives:

```
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/mjgalindo/ClionProjects/ThreadTest/cmake-build-debug
[ 33%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/ThreadTest.dir/main.cpp.o
[ 66%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/ThreadTest.dir/foo.cpp.o
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/thread:39:0,
                 from /home/mjgalindo/ClionProjects/ThreadTest/foo.cpp:3:
/usr/include/c++/6/functional: In instantiation of ‘struct std::_Bind_simple<std::_Mem_fn<void (Foo::*)(unsigned int, unsigned int, std::vector<unsigned int>&)>(Foo*, unsigned int, unsigned int, std::reference_wrapper<std::vector<int> >)>’:
/usr/include/c++/6/thread:137:26:   required from ‘std::thread::thread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = void (Foo::*)(unsigned int, unsigned int, std::vector<unsigned int>&); _Args = {Foo*, unsigned int&, unsigned int&, std::reference_wrapper<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >}]’
/home/mjgalindo/ClionProjects/ThreadTest/foo.cpp:15:89:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/6/functional:1374:61: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘class std::result_of<std::_Mem_fn<void (Foo::*)(unsigned int, unsigned int, std::vector<unsigned int>&)>(Foo*, unsigned int, unsigned int, std::reference_wrapper<std::vector<int> >)>’
       typedef typename result_of<_Callable(_Args...)>::type result_type;
                                                             ^~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/6/functional:1395:9: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘class std::result_of<std::_Mem_fn<void (Foo::*)(unsigned int, unsigned int, std::vector<unsigned int>&)>(Foo*, unsigned int, unsigned int, std::reference_wrapper<std::vector<int> >)>’
         _M_invoke(_Index_tuple<_Indices...>)
         ^~~~~~~~~
CMakeFiles/ThreadTest.dir/build.make:86: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/ThreadTest.dir/foo.cpp.o' failed
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/ThreadTest.dir/foo.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/ThreadTest.dir/all' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/ThreadTest.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:79: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/ThreadTest.dir/rule' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/ThreadTest.dir/rule] Error 2
Makefile:118: recipe for target 'ThreadTest' failed
make: *** [ThreadTest] Error 2
```

I've seen many questions similar to this one but all of them didn't use the this parameter in the thread constructor or didn't use ref. My guess is I'm linking pthread wrong but its just conjecture.

Comment: Belt and suspenders programming: the code creates a vector whose size is `threads`, runs a `for` loop that starts at 0 and exits when the index is `threads`, and just in case, uses `at()` to check that the index is in bounds.

Comment: @PeteBecker with that you mean to say at() is redundant in this case? I always used [] until I found that at() was safer.

Comment: Yes, `at()` is redundant. It's only "safer" if it adds something important that isn't otherwise there. Your loop as written correctly indexes into the vector, and checking whether the index is valid doesn't add anything to what's already there. If you write loops correctly there is rarely a need for additional checking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
std::vector<int> values;

... std::vector<unsigned int> &container) { ...
```

`std::vector<int>` and `std::vector<unsigned int>` are unrelated types. There is no conversion from one to another.

Comment: Dumb question, the real code doesn't have this same issue so it was irrelavant in the end... Still, the error message is the same in both cases and even with this one solved it doesn't work giving "terminate called without an active exception" which should be a topic for another question.