# C++ Thread Error - compile-time error with class argument

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, cygwin

I found the page [C++ thread error: no type named type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40817345/c-thread-error-no-type-named-type), with a similar error message to the one I am reporting below.  The answer on that page doesn't cover this case, as best I can tell.  Admittedly, there must be something simple that I am simply clueless about here.

I have been trying use threads in a C++ program I am working on.  I had an initial version working with `boost::thread` without any problems.  This morning, I tried to rewrite my code to use `std::thread` instead of `boost::thread`.  That's when I suddenly ran into compile-time errors that I do not understand.  I have reduced the problem to the following piece of code.

The upshot?  As soon as I try to pass a reference to one of my own user-defined classes as a function argument, the program fails to compile.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

class TestClass { } ;

void testfunc1 ( void )           { std::cout << "Hello World TF1" << std::endl ; }
void testfunc2 ( double val )     { std::cout << "Hello World TF2" << std::endl ; }
void testfunc3 ( TestClass & tc ) { std::cout << "Hello World TF3" << std::endl ; }

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    std::thread t1 ( testfunc1 ) ;

    double tv ;
    std::thread t2 ( testfunc2, tv ) ;

    TestClass tc ;
    std::thread t3 ( testfunc3, tc ) ;    //  compiler generates error here

    return 0 ;
}
```

The code will compile as long as I comment out that last line of code.  When it is present, however, I get the following compile-time error.

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/include/c++/thread:39:0,
                 from test.cpp:3:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/include/c++/functional: In instantiation of ‘struct std::_Bind_simple<void (*(TestClass))(TestClass&)>’:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/include/c++/thread:142:59:   required from ‘std::thread::thread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = void (&)(TestClass&); _Args = {TestClass&}]’
test.cpp:19:33:   required from here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/include/c++/functional:1505:61: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘class std::result_of<void (*(TestClass))(TestClass&)>’
       typedef typename result_of<_Callable(_Args...)>::type result_type;
                                                             ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/include/c++/functional:1526:9: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘class std::result_of<void (*(TestClass))(TestClass&)>’
         _M_invoke(_Index_tuple<_Indices...>)
```

There is clearly some kind of type-related issue, but I can't decipher this error message.  Any idea what the issue is?  (I happen to be using Cygwin on a Windows 10 machine, but I don't think that's relevant to the problem described.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `std::thread` can't store C++ references, it's similar to how `std::vector<T&>` can't exist. So, in order to pass references around, there's a [reference wrapper](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper) in the standard library. It's basically a pointer under the hood, which mimics some of the language-wise reference's behavior. The `std::ref` and `std::cref` (for const references) functions are used to create an object of `std::reference_wrapper` (they're convenient functions, as they have template type deduction and shorter names).

The only thing you have to add in your code is the `std::ref` function call, like so:

```
TestClass tc;
std::thread t3(testfunc3, std::ref(tc));
```

Comment: Thank you!  Never would have figured that out on my own.  Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

To pass references you need to use the [`std::ref`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref) wrapper:

```
std::thread t3 ( testfunc3, std::ref ( tc ) ) ;
```

Comment: Thanks!  Appreciate the help.